# Are there any tricks to help me find all the Animus Data Fragments?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I've collected a few of the Animus Data Fragments, but they seem like the feathers in previous games - there are a ton of them, and they're hard to see.  I find that without assistance, finding these objects is just too time consuming and irritating.  Is there a map or some trick to finding all of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there's one passing in your field of vision when you are in eagle vision, it will appear on your map. When at 50, you will receive a free map that show them all in your map.

Comment: I've started just sweeping across the horizon with Eagle Vision to see if I can't pick them up, and I've hit a good half dozen or so.  The map should be quite helpful once I get that far along.

Comment: I'll also note that the minimap icons for many things (including the fragments) are disabled while Eagle Vision is active.  Kind of weird that they leave the map on, but remove most of the icons, but I guess it kind of fits with the eagle vision theme.

Answer (score 1):

Actually once you go far enough into the game, they will start to appear on the map for you after you have obtained a minimum amount of fragments.  IIRC, I was starting Sequence 6 (some time just after a major break in the story) with ~60 when this happened, though Shinrai confirms the minimum is 50.  There was no map to buy.

Comment: You need 50 for them to show up on the map.

Answer (score 0):

[This site](http://www.gamedynamo.com/article/showarticle/2440/en/Assassins_Creed_Revelations_Map_-_Animus_Data_Fragments_Memoir_Pages_Treasure_Chest_Locations) has maps of each area that mark where the Animus Data Fragments are, and also has a video guide for each location on the maps.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest way is to buy some chest location books/maps and activate eagle vision and free-styling everywhere getting the chests (this way you won't be wasting your time, but getting money etc.) and if you don't see any fragments, your eagle vision will and set a marker on the map. Or just freestyle like a maniac everywhere and get the fragments (which takes a long time)